# Shout out to Derek F

Tags: discussion

Not exactly a question but I continue to be astonished by the amount of patience, detail, empathy, and instruction [Derek F](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/24889/derek-f) gives in his answers to relative newbie Apex developers

Here's an [example](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/368683/2602) but there have been many more in recent months.

As a frequent contributor myself, I am in awe over this level of comprehensiveness, mostly in terms of the time it takes to write up and nicely format the answer, including relevant links.

Should we all be so helpful to the new users of the Platform.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thanks for the shout out!

Brevity is definitely something I aim to improve at in general, but I'm always glad to hear when my more extended answers really hit the nail on the head (and on occasion, the next nail or two thereafter).

I feel that trying to get into the OP's headspace to understand why approach X was taken so we can highlight how approach Y is better helps lead to deeper understanding. It's also a pretty good mental exercise. I too hope we can see more support for our platform fledglings and continue to fight against the perception of StackExchange/StackOverflow coldness and brusqueness.

Comment: And in a delicious twist of irony, it took me around the same amount of time to write this (609 characters) as it did to write the linked answer (~5000 characters).

Comment: Well worth the time as now I've added "platform fledglings" into my vocabulary.

Comment: @DerekF are you on Salesforce Discord Exchange? We would love to have you in! https://join.sfxd.org

Comment: @AtlasCan I am now